# Django 1.8 Cache busting + Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, caching, amazon-s3

I´ve been doing some research, and I have found articles explaining how to use Django's(1.8) cache busting, but they don´t explain my situation.

I am using S3 (and it works) with the following setting in settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE= 'pms.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
```

In order to use cache busting the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage) say I have to set: `STATICFILES_STORAGE='django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

I don´t know what setting to use in order to use both S3 and cache busting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I finally found a workaround.

In order to be able to upload my files to 2 different folders (static and uploads) in my S3 bucket I have this in my `settings.py` file:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myapp.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myapp.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
```

And this in the `myapp.s3utils.py` file:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='uploads')
```

But I couldn´t use Django´s cache busting. 
The solution was to change my `myapp.s3utils.py` file to:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin

class CustomS3Storage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: CustomS3Storage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='uploads')
```

Basically it adds the **ManiFestfilesMixin**, which allows you to use cache busting.

As a side note, you can see that I am only using cache busting for the static files, but not for the uploads files. That is why the **MediaRootS3BotoStorage** calls the **S3BotoStorage** class instead of the **CustomS3Storage**.
I do it this way because the uploads files are not stored in my server (the static files are), they are stored directly in the S3 bucket, so when I ran the **collectstatic** they are not on my server, so I don´t have to add the hash to the names.

Comment: Wow, this save my day!! 

I have been dealing with this for a couple of hours without any success. I don't understand why this answer doesn't have more positive votes. This simple change on the s3utils.py works like a charm for me :)

Thanks mate!!!

Comment: Where does `staticfiles.json` get stored in this case, in S3 or in the local filesystem? And is it read with every request?

Comment: To answer my question, it seems that `staticfiles.json` gets stored in S3, publicly viewable, and it is not read with every request.

Comment: I had some issues with `ManifestFilesMixin` and erroneous files being uploaded to S3. If your having that problem take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309821/collectstatic-incorrectly-creates-multiple-css-files-in-s3/52323409#52323409