# collectstatic incorrectly creates multiple CSS files in S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, wagtail, django-storage

I have uploading files to S3 working fine with my Wagtail/django application (both static and uploads). Now I'm trying to use `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` to enable cache busting. The urls are correctly being generated by the application and files are being copied with hashes to S3.

But each time I run `collectstatic` some files get copied twice to S3 - each with a different hash. So far the issue is ocurring for all CSS files.

`file.a.css` is loaded by the application and is the file referenced in `staticfiles.json` - however it is a 20.0B file in S3 (should be 6.3KB).

`file.b.css` has the correct contents in S3 - however it does NOT appear in the output generated by `collectstatic`.

```
# custom_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class CachedS3Storage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    pass


class StaticStorage(CachedS3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False
```

Deps:

```
"boto==2.47.0",
"boto3==1.4.4",
"django-storages==1.5.2"
"Django==2.0.8"
```

Any pointers on where to look to track down this issue would be appreciated! :)

Edit:

Looking more carefully at all the files copied to S3 the issue is ONLY occurring for CSS files.

Disabling pushing assets to S3 and writing them to the local filesystem works as expected.

Edit 2:

Updated all the deps to the latest version - same behavior as above.

Comment: did you try to restart Django on prod?

Comment: I did... Many times :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually stumbled across this issue in [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/488) issue tracker which then lead me to [a very similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999582/collectstatic-creates-empty-files/51270732#51270732).

Between these two pages I managed to resolve the issue. I did the following to get `django-storages` + `ManifestStaticFilesStorage` + S3 to work together:

```
# custom_storages.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import ManifestFilesMixin
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage  # note boto3!!


class PatchedS3StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        if hasattr(content, 'seek') and hasattr(content, 'seekable') and content.seekable():
            content.seek(0)
        return super()._save(name, content)


class CachedS3Storage(ManifestFilesMixin, PatchedS3StaticStorage):
    pass


class StaticStorage(CachedS3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False
```

Note that I had to use `boto3` to get this to work `django-storages` must be >= 1.5 to use `boto3`. I removed `boto` as a dep. My final deps were:

```
"boto3==1.4.4",
"django-storages==1.7.1"
"Django==2.0.8"
```